# React Typescript Router(5.1.8) data is not passing to other component as a query params

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

When I click the button I want to navigate to another component and need to pass some data as query parameters. below is my react code.

interface Props {

```
    }
    
    const App: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
    
    
     return (
              <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                   <Route path="/admin/NotificationManager/" exact  component={NotificationPanelComponent} />
                  <Route path="/admin/NotificationManager/notification/new" exact  component={NewNotification} />
                  <Route path="/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit/:notificationId" exact component={NewNotification}/>
                </Switch>
              </BrowserRouter>
              
              
               <Button
                                onClick={() => {
    
                                     history.push('/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit?notificationId=1234');
    
                                }}
                                text = "EDIT"
                                classN="editB"
                                disabled={false}
                            />
        );
    
    }

export default App;
```

---

```
interface Props{
    

}



const NewNotification: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {

    const location = useLocation();
    const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

    console.log("query",query); // nothing prints

    const {notificationId} = useParams<{notificationId:string}>();//nothing print


}

export default NewNotification;
```

when I try to print the params value in navigated component nothing prints and even the page is not loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are navigating to `"/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit?notificationId=1234"`.

Here the path is `"/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit"` and a queryString search is `"?notificationId=1234"`. There is no ***exactly*** matching path for `"/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit"`.

These are the routes you render:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/admin/NotificationManager/"
      exact
      component={NotificationPanelComponent}
    />
    <Route
      path="/admin/NotificationManager/notification/new"
      exact
      component={NewNotification}
    />
    <Route 
      path="/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit/:notificationId"
      exact
      component={NewNotification}
    />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

## Solution(s)

In the `NewNotification` you are trying a couple methods for accessing this notification id value:

1. QueryString search params

   ```
   const location = useLocation();
   const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
   ```

   Here you would need to access the `notificationId` value by accessing the appropriate queryString `get` method, i.e. `query.get("notificationId")`.

   To address, you need to fix the route so it can match this path you are attempting to route to:

   ```
   <Route 
     path="/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit"
     exact
     component={NewNotification}
   />
   ```

   Access the queryString value in the routed component:

   ```
   const location = useLocation();
   const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
   const notificationId = query.get("notificationId");
   ```
2. Route path params

   ```
   const { notificationId } = useParams<{notificationId:string}>();
   ```

   Here you would need to pass `notificationId` as a route param ***and then*** also navigate to the correct path. Use a templated string to inject the `notificationId` into the path.

   ```
   history.push(`/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit/${1234}`);
   ```

   Or use the [`generatePath`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/generatePath) utility.

   ```
   history.push(generatePath(
     "/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit/:notificationId",
     { notificationId: 1234 }
   ));
   ```

   Access the `notificationId` route param in the routed component:

   ```
   const { notificationId } = useParams<{notificationId:string}>();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

React router in functional components doesnt pass route params as props. They can by accessed by `useParams()` hook.
In your case if you want to obtain `notificationId` in `NewNotification.tsx`

```
const {notificationId} = useParams();
```

PS: dont confuse url parameters and search query, `URLSearchParams(location.search);` will acces search query, which is specified in url as `http://something.com/page?firstQuery=1&secondQuery=something`

Comment: Reading your question again, maybe i misunderstood your problem. If you really want to use  search query, it looks like your history.push doesnt work properly... try to pass string instead of object `history.push('/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit?notificationId=1234');`

Comment: when i try like this history.push('/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit?notificationId=1234'); still page not loading and no errors in console

Comment: If you want to use params from react-router its different than query string. to pass it to `useParams`, you must follow your route path specified in `<Route>`. What i am trying to say is that for `useParams` you must use route `/admin/NotificationManager/notification/edit/1234`. In your route is specified that after `/edit` comes `/:notificiationId` which is your dynamic path param.